Data Changes in Timeseries Prediction
I'm interested in playing with some timeseries prediction for the stock market. I'd like to incorporate other features but ran into an issue - companies publish their earnings, but they also often publish updated figures up to a year later, which means that the original figures AND the updated figures both influence the ongoing price of the stock (presumably). Is there any kind of literature for accounting for data changes/updates in timeseries predictions?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection
